# The type com.sun.portal.portletcontainer.taglib.PropertyBaseTag cannot be resolved

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-aui

I try to extend Liferay AUI Input Tag. for that I create one class as

```
package ae.rak.ega.tag;

import com.liferay.taglib.aui.InputTag;


public class TestInputTag extends InputTag {

}
```

but it show error message

> The type com.sun.portal.portletcontainer.taglib.PropertyBaseTag cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

how I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have't class `com.sun.portal.portletcontainer.taglib.PropertyBaseTag` in your classpath, try to add the jar with this class in your classpath.